# Unity 2D: Why does my character move through other geometry without stopping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever using A or D my character (2 dimensional game object) is not stopped by the other game objects. The character has a character controller component attached as well as an animation controller with 3 animations (Idle, Walk and Land).

```
//Variables
public float speed = 10F;
public float jumpSpeed = 15F; 
public float gravity = 20F;
public float airSpeed = 5F;
public Vector2 moveDirectionResultant = Vector2.zero;
private CharacterController controller;
private Animator animator;


void Start() {

    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update() {

    animator.SetFloat ("AirSpeed", moveDirectionResultant.y);

    if (controller.isGrounded) 
    {
        animator.SetBool("Grounded", true);
        animator.SetBool("Move", false);

                    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) 
                    {
            moveDirectionResultant.y = jumpSpeed;
                    }

                    else
                    {
            moveDirectionResultant.y =  0;
                    }


                    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
                    {
            transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
            animator.SetBool("Move", true);
                    }

                    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) 
                    {
            transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
            animator.SetBool("Move", true);
                    }

    }

    else 
    {
        animator.SetBool("Grounded", false);
        animator.SetBool("Move", false);

                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
                {
            transform.Translate(airSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);;
                }

                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) 
                {
            transform.Translate(-airSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);;
                }



    }



    //Applying gravity to the controller
    moveDirectionResultant.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    //Making the character move
    controller.Move(moveDirectionResultant * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

I am relatively new to coding, so if the solution is obvious, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a `RigidBody2D` and `BoxCollider2D` to your gameobject, as well as to any gameobjects which you would like to collide with. If you'd like to have the collision cause an event to occur (a method to be called) use the `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)` method within a script attached to the gameobject. This tutorial video from unity's website goes into detail about 2d character control and animation: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! It said "Cant add due to conflicting component!" which is the character controller.

Comment: Sorry, that's correct, the character controller replaces the functionality. Do you have collider components on all of the other objects in the scene you'd like to collide with?

Comment: They all have the box collider that unity creates when the object is created.

Comment: I found this video on the unity website detailing how to set up a 2D character controller: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers
Instead of using a CharacterController, he is instead using a RigidBody2D, a BoxCollider2D, and then proceeds to write his own controller script. Hopefully that video will explain how it's done in 2D, as it seems to be a different approach than 3D.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this would be a much better technique!

Comment: No problem, I'll edit the answer to include the video for others :)